# How to draw multiple lines with Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I am trying to draw a plot with two lines. Both with different colors. And different labels. This is what I have come up with.

[image]

This is code that I have written.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Summer-2020/URMC/training_x_total_data_ones.csv", header=None)
data2 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Summer-2020/URMC/training_x_total_data_zeroes.csv", header=None)

sns.lineplot(data=data1, color="red")
sns.lineplot(data=data2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

This is how my dataset looks like

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So, I just added another color in the second line and that seemed to work.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 100)

mu1, sigma1 = 0.5, 1
t = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 100)

sns.lineplot(data= s, color = "red")
sns.lineplot(data= t, color ="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: I think it also has to do with my dataset. I have edited the question and added a screenshot of both of my datasets.

Comment: Did you try adding the parameter, hue? i.e sns.lineplot(data=data1, hue=<column name>)

Comment: ValueError: The following variable cannot be assigned with wide-form data: `hue`

Comment: This is what I tried: sns.lineplot(data=data1, hue='0')

Comment: This is what I did, and it worked for me, sns.lineplot(data= s, hue = s)
sns.lineplot(data= t, hue=t), where s and t are my variable names. In your case, since you only have 1 column, you can give the name of the data, ie. data1, and data2 ? Try that.

Comment: Also based on your error, since your data is in wide form, you might want to try sns.relplot(data= data1, kind= "line", hue= data1). Here is the documentation for that, https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the `x` and `y` of the call to `sns.lineplot`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(10)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,
                    'y':np.sin(x)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,
                    'y':x**2})

sns.lineplot(data=df1, x='x', y='y', color="red")
sns.lineplot(data=df2, x='x', y='y')
```

[image]

Without doing so, I get a similar plot as yours.

Comment: I think it also has to do with my dataset. I have edited the question and added a screenshot of both of my datasets.